# mysql query not working in Node js, same query working on terminal

Tags: mysql, node.js

facing one issue related to MySQL query as mentioned below,

I have one query which returns me near by users as given below,

**SELECT *, SQRT(POW(69.1 * (user_lat - '+startlat+'), 2) + POW(69.1 * ('+startlng+' - user_long) * COS(user_lat / 57.3), 2)) AS distance FROM users WHERE NOT user_id = '+user_id+' HAVING distance < '+distance+' ORDER BY distance;**

which looks after putting values,

**SELECT *, SQRT(POW(69.1 * (user_lat - 18.5914), 2) + POW(69.1 * (73.917 - user_long) * COS(user_lat / 57.3), 2)) AS distance FROM users WHERE NOT user_id = 1 HAVING distance < 10 ORDER BY distance;**

If I am hitting the same query from node.js it returns me error as given below but at the same time if I hit this query through terminal it returns results.PFA [image]

**...../node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:79
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^
ReferenceError: result is not defined
......**

Node JS code :

```
near_by_user: function (req, res) {

    var startlat = parseFloat(req.query.user_lat);
    var startlng = parseFloat(req.query.user_long);
    var distance = parseFloat(req.query.distance);
    var user_id = parseInt(req.query.user_id);

    if ((startlat != null) && (startlng != null) && (distance != null) && (user_id != null)) {

        var sql_query = 'SELECT *, SQRT(POW(69.1 * (user_lat - '+startlat+'), 2) + POW(69.1 * ('+startlng+' - user_long) * COS(user_lat / 57.3), 2)) AS distance FROM users WHERE NOT user_id = '+user_id+' HAVING distance < '+distance+' ORDER BY distance';
        console.log(sql_query);

        db_conn.query(sql_query, function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                res.send({
                    "error": true,
                    "message": "Somthing wrong with db upadate !!!!"
                });
            } else {
                console.log(result[0].json);
                res.send({
                    "error": false,
                    "users": results
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.send({
            "error": true,
            "message": "Invalid Params !!!!"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your Nodejs code?

Comment: Please check updated node js code.

Comment: You used `console.log(result[0].json);` instead `console.log(results[0].json);`. That's why you got a RefenceError. Just typo :)

Answer (score 0):

this error is when you have another error (syntaxis normally) inside your block that treat the error. Like Dylan Dang  saw it.

Another error is produced and the mysql error is not launched.